# Need regex extraction help in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a html source and needs to retrieve values between `<h1>15</h1>` tag. 
`<h1>` instance is appearing many times in full html code.

Below is the sample portion of html code

```
<div class="rs_text_11_may">
    <p>Rs</p>
    <h1>15</h1>
</div>
```

I tried a lot but i didnt achieve it. Help me friends...

Answer (score 0):

You need following regex: `(?<=<h1>).+?(?=</h1>)` This works fine in C#.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=<h1>).+?(?=</h1>)");
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(@"<h1>15</h1><h1>14</h1>", 0);
```

Comment: What about headlines like this: `<h1 class="new">foo</h1>`?

Comment: Exactly i need to extract "15" from <h1> tag.                    <div class="rs_text_11_may">
    <p>Rs</p>
    <h1>15</h1>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

**Try this (a far better way is to use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087) for this not RegEx)**

```
Public Function test() As Boolean
        Try
            Dim xe As XElement = <div class="rs_text_11_may">
                                     <p>Rs</p>
                                     <h1>15</h1>
                                 </div>
            Dim h1s = xe...<h1>
            For Each ele As XElement In h1s
                MsgBox(ele.Value)
            Next
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: Exactly i need to extract "15" from <h1> tag. <div class="rs_text_11_may"> <p>Rs</p> <h1>15</h1> </div>